# Having multiple values under one parameter in objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I've got a problem with my program a bit, here is the the code

```
children_and_parents = {}

class Parent_Child:
   def __init__(self, parent, child):
      self.parent = parent
      self.child = child

def read_data(filename):
   with open(filename) as f:
      parent, child = line.rstrip("\n").split("->")
      children_and_parents[parent] = Parent_Child(parent, child)
```

the problem is in the file I've got parents who have more than 1 children example:

Mary->Patricia

Mary->Lisa

but when i call children_and_parents["Mary"].child I get only Lisa, but i should get Patricia and Lisa, also i would like them to be different "entities" so i can call and use them later on

Comment: You are overwriting Mary's child from Patricia to Lisa, i.e. Patricia gets disowned. My suggestion is to have `self.child = []` be a list to which you append to.

Comment: It looks like `children_and_parents` is an array, so `children_and_parents['xxx'] will only contain the last single `Parent_Child` object you added to it.

Comment: it is a dictionary, children_and_parents = {} , added to the question, sorry my mistake

Comment: This class seems like overkill if this is all it contains. I'd use a dict with string key (parent) mapped to array of value strings (children).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have multiple children like this:

```
children_and_parents = {}

class Parent_Child:
    def __init__(self, parent, child):
        self.parent = parent
        self.child = [child]

def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        parent, child = line.rstrip("\n").split("->")
        if parent in children_and_parents:
            # append the child
            children_and_parents[parent].child.append(child)
        else: 
            children_and_parents[parent] = Parent_Child(parent, child)
```

That makes the child as a list and checks if the parent already exists before creating

Comment: gives my an error: 'Parent_Child' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: My bad. Should be fixed now. I was not accessing the child attribute

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can change the following line

```
  children_and_parents[parent] = Parent_Child(parent, child)
```

to something like

```
  children_and_parents.setdefault(parent, []).append(Parent_Child(parent, child))
```